# urdf_tutorial no such file or directory

Tags: ros2, urdf, ros2-launch, urdf-tutorial

I am using the urdf_tutorial. I cannot create an urdf file inside urdf folder, so I create the urdf file in the home directory. When I want to launch the urdf file, I get an error that no such file or directory.

How can I tell the program to look at the home directory?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you would need to give an absolute path, rather than a relative one.